# How do I implement one-to-one relationship and leverage in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ecmascript-6

This is my UserSchema:

```
const UserSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, maxlength: 255, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, maxlength: 255, required: true },
    nickname: { type: String, maxlength: 255 },
    last_login: { type: Date },
    token: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Token' },
});
```

This is my TokenSchema:

```
const EXPIRES = 1 * 60 * 60;  // set 1 hr
const TokenSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    key: { type: String, unique: true},
    created_at: { type: Date, expires: EXPIRES , default: Date},
    _user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User' },
});
```

(1) Save

If I have a user: `Mary`, it will get a token. This is my method as following:

```
mary = new User({email: 'mary@example.com', ...})
token = new Token({_user: mary})
token.save()
```

Is it right? Need I to take `token` saving in user? for example:

```
mary.token = token;
mary.save()
```

(2) Get

Next, I use token's key to parse its user. This is my method as following:

```
let authorization = req.header('authorization');
Token.findOne({key: authorization }).populate('_user').exec(cb)
```

Is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the [population doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), you can try to save the document as below

1) **Save**

```
var token = new Token({_user: mary});
token.save(function(err) {
    if (err) return err;

    var mary = new User({
           email: 'mary@example.com', 
           // ...
           token: token._id // assign token id to user
        });
    mary.save(function(err) {
        if (err) return err;

        Token.update({_id: token._id}, 
                     {_user: mary._id}, // update token with user id
                     function(err) { });
    });
});
```

2) **Get** method you used seems correct.